# Rails Admin dynamic fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Event that has an attribute `number_of_events`. Then I have another model EventTime.

```
model Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :event_times
end

model EventTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  # and a bunch of fields such as event start, max attendees, ...
end
```

Please note that I cannot alter attributes!

In rails admin, whenever number_of_events changes, it should create a new row with even_time fields.

For example, when `number_of_events` is set to  5, it should create 5 rows, each row containing all the fields from EventTime. After the submission of Event, it should create 5 EventTime records with event_id of my event.

I already have a way to display the fields and the number of rows accordingly to the number_of_events. However, I have an issue creating the records.

```
config.model Event do

    edit do
      field :number_of_events
      field :event_times do
        partial :event_times_partial
      end
    end
end
```

My question is - how can I create data accordingly to my view or parameters that I pass through? Is there a way how to override controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Event` model is missing [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
Which allow *Event* model to save *EventTime* Records as well.

```
model Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :event_times
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_times
end
```